# How to close the Database connection defined in another function in current function

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql-9.3

'''
def Database_connection():
try:
# PostgreSQL connection
Postgres_connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres", password="password", host="127.0.0.1",
port="5432", database="Maps")
Postgres_cursor = Postgres_connection.cursor()
except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error1:
print("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error1)
return Postgres_connection,Postgres_cursor

```
def Database_connection_close():
    Postgres_connection=Database_connection()
    Postgres_connection.close()
```

'''

Comment: def Database_connection():
        try:
            # PostgreSQL connection
            Postgres_connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres", password="password", host="127.0.0.1",port="5432", database="Maps")
            Postgres_cursor = Postgres_connection.cursor()
        except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error1:
            print("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error1)
            return Postgres_connection,Postgres_cursor

Comment: above is the connect function i tried to close connection in another function, giving error.

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: i have defined a postgres database connection in Database_connection() function
i want close that database connection in Database_connection_close() function
but when i tried using the code mentioned above giving error.